# Pyodbc default types for numbers

Tags: python, sql-server, types, pyodbc, pandas

I am using pyodbc to query data from SQL Server and then perform operations on it in `pandas`. What I have noticed is that some calculated numeric columns are returned as decimal.Decimal and others as float. This is problematic as arithmetic operands can't performed on results of two different types.

What is the best way to resolve it? Is there a pydobc setting to coerce decimal.Decimal to float? Should I do the conversion myself? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/DataTypes#Results) are conversion tables (under the `Results` heading for Python 2.x and 3.x) detailing the conversions between ODBC and Python data types.

Either `CAST` the result as mentioned in @Aaron's answer, or change the source data type in the database.

With some more detail (specific column data type, sample data, flexibility of database changes), we could help decide which option is best.

Comment: The database schema is a bit messy, with decimal, numeric, and float all used interchangeably without much rhyme that I could decipher. I ended up casting decimal to float on python side. The longterm solution for me is going to modify the intermediate library that I have between pyodbc and business to have an option to coerce decimals and numerics to float (and perhaps other types too).

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote the query I'd recommend just using `CAST` to control the data type. I always explicitly cast computed columns in SQL Server

```
SELECT CAST(ColumnA/ColumnB AS FLOAT) AS 'FieldA' FROM Table
```

Comment: I considered doing that, but sql queries are ugly as they are already without having to add code accommodate client libraries. There should really be solution that you perform once per query on the client, perhaps wrapping execute() that does this for you.